# how to set different texture to sprites sharing one shader in cocos2d

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, lua, cocos2d-x, shader

I'm making a rain scene with 4 different rain drop textures, each rain drop sprite randomly choose a rain drop texture when it's created and added to the screen. All the rain drop sprite share a same shader.

The problem is, when I add a new rain drop onto the screen, all former rain drops that have been added to the scene change its texture to be the same as the new rain drop.

my code is as follows:

```
local function addOneRainDrop()
    local rainStyleNumber = math.random(1,4)
    local rainDrop = cc.Sprite:create("rainDrop"..tostring(rainStyleNumber)..".png")
    rainShader:use()
    rainShader:updateUniforms()
    rainShader:setUniformsForBuiltins()
    gl.activeTexture(GL_TEXTURE1)    -- here may be the reason
    gl.bindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, rainDrop:getTexture():getName())
    gl.activeTexture(GL_TEXTURE2)
    gl.bindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, rainNormal[rainStyleNumber]:getName())
    gl.activeTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)

    rainDrop:setGLProgram(rainShader)
    rainDropLayer:addChild(rainDrop)
end
```

In my shader, I just sample CC_Texture0, CC_Texture1, CC_Texture2 and output color. It's not the shader's problem, I think. I don't know how Cocos2d manage it's shader's state and uniforms for different sprites, maybe directly inherit from CCSprite, overwrite "draw" and manage the texture by my self can solve the problem but it's a little bit complicated.

Any better ideas?

=============================================================================

UPDATE:

I find out that I can use GLProgramState to store uniforms for each sprite. Quote from cocos2d's website

> A GLProgram can be used by thousands of Nodes, but if different uniform values are going to be used, then each node will need its own GLProgramState

So I changed my code to following:

```
local function addOneRainDrop()
    local rainStyleNumber = math.random(1,4)
    local rainDrop = cc.Sprite:create("rainDrop"..tostring(rainStyleNumber)..".png")
    local glprogramstate = cc.GLProgramState:getOrCreateWithGLProgram(rainShader);
    glprogramstate:setUniformTexture("rainDrop", rainDrop:getTexture():getName());
    glprogramstate:setUniformTexture("textureBackground", bg:getTexture():getName());
    glprogramstate:setUniformTexture("rainDropNormals", rainNormal[rainStyleNumber]:getName());
    rainDrop:setGLProgramState(glprogramstate);
    rainDropLayer:addChild(rainDrop)
end
```

Unfortunately, all the sprites still use the same texture. Does this have something to do with batchedNode?

Comment: It's possible that the `TEXTURE1` and `TEXTURE2` texture units are being over-written by another GL operation later in time (they're used quite often). You may have to set the `TEXTURE1` and `TEXTURE2` units before the GL draw. I had a similar issue. The solution for me was to simply set the texture unit to `TEXTURE3` and `TEXTURE4` as I knew no other part of the API was setting those texture units AND I didn't have access to the GL state before the draw happened.

Comment: @PeqNP  you are right, My solution is to recreate the same shaders for different rain drop. Fortunately I have only 4 different rain drop textures which means I only have to create the same shaders 4 times with different texture and all rain drops using the same texture can use the same shader. But I don't know how to handle it if every rain drop has different textures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with you utilisation of **getOrCreateWithGLProgram()** which always returns the same **GLProgramState** because it caches using your **rainShader** as key.

---

What I've done is:

### 1) Create a method that will create or return your shader program

```
    static GLProgram* getOrCreateShader(std::string name, const GLchar* vert, const GLchar* frag)
    {
        auto cache = GLProgramCache::getInstance();
        auto prog = cache->getGLProgram(name);
        if(prog == nullptr)
        {
            prog = GLProgram::createWithByteArrays(vert, frag);
            cache->addGLProgram(prog, name);
        }
        return prog;
    }
```

My method creates a program from a GLchar buffer, but you can create a new one which uses disk files.

### 2) For each of your sprites, you create a new GLProgramState from your GLProgram

```
        auto program = getOrCreateShader("rainShaderName", vertexProgram, fragmentProgram);
        auto programState = GLProgramState::create(program);

        Sprite* sprite = Sprite::create("yourSpriteImage.png");
        programState->setUniformTxeture("u_texture", sprite->getTexture());
        sprite->setGLProgramState(programState);
```

This way, the shader program will only be created once, and you'll have a unique GLProgramState per sprite.